# Deleting all small files whose filename has a space

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I want to do

```
@for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %A in (`dir /s /b *.mp4`) do @If %~zA LSS 2048 del %A
```

But the filenames have spaces in them and the

```
del %A
```

seems to not include the part of the filename that is after the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If filenames have spaces in them you have to use quotes around them (") in the del command and why are you using semicolom (;) as a delimeter?

for /f  "delims=" %A in ('dir /s /b *.mp4') do @If %~zA LSS 2048 del "%A"

Answer (score 0):

This approach looks complicated to me.  While it does seem to work, I wonder if this isn't a slightly simpler approach:

`for /R %A in (*.mp4) do @If %~zA LSS 2048 echo del "%A"`

(I sometimes like to start my tests with "echo" to make sure that produces the results I expect, before I repeat the command with the "echo" command removed.  This is especially true with something like a delete command.)